# Problema com animação no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, floatingactionbutton

Criei um `Float Buttom` para iniciar uma animação, mas quando clico nele, a animação não ocorre. Já fiz o *debug* para verificar o método que inicia a animação e ele ocorre normalmente. Acredito que possa ser algum problema do XML.

o XML da animação:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

O `Listener` do `Float Buttom` na `Main Activity`:

```
botaoAjuda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                R.anim.tutorialanim);
        animation.start();
        Log.d("anim: ",animation+"");
    }
});
```

e esse `Float Buttom` está num *layout* que eu chamo no *layout* do `Main Activity` com include:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/helpButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
```

O include na `Main Activity`:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de:

```
animation.start();
```

você deve usar:

```
botaoAjuda.startAnimation(animation);
```

Perceba que você não atribuiu nenhuma animação ao botão, simplesmente criou uma variável do tipo `Animation` dentro dele.

Comment: Compreendi! mas no meu caso, eu precisaria escurecer a tela inteira e não sei como chamar ela para dar esse start

Comment: @MikhaelAraujo Uma coisa é colocar ação no botão, outra coisa é fazer com que o botão execute uma ação. Você precisa definir isso na sua pergunta. Sugiro que faça uma pergunta ou edite essa detalhando melhor seu problema nesse sentido.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que sua animação não é aplicada em nenhuma **View**, a não ser nela mesma, que não é uma **view**.

Quando você cria uma animação via XML, o seu objetivo é animar alguma view pertencente ao seu layout, e isto não irá ocorrer se você não apontar sua animação para nenhuma delas.

**Veja**:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
            R.anim.tutorialanim);

ImageView mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view22);
mView.startAnimation(animation); // uma view qualquer definida no seu layout
```

Comment: ah sim... entendi agora. mas no caso, eu queria escurecer a tela inteira

Comment: Use ObjectAnimation, com ele você pode facilmente fazer o efeito de fade em um objeto, a tela iria escurecer pouco a pouco, recomento o vídeo do Thiengo Calopsita no youtube, ele fala sobre isso.